# How to do a shorthand if-then in jQuery? Are these chainable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

Actually two questions:

I like the shorthand *IF-ELSE* in [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) like so:

```
var some == true ? "it's true" : "it's false";
```

Is there a corresponding *IF-THEN*, because this:

```
   var some == true ? "it's true"
```

doesn't seem to work.

Also, would something like this be chainable in regular jQuery? Like so:

```
  some.addClass("hello")
      .find(".other").css("width","100px").end()
      // chained if
      .hasClass("one") ? some.css("border","1px solid red")
      .removeClass("hello")
```

Now that would be nice, wouldn't it? Is this possible?

Comment: `var some == true ? "it's true" : "it's false";` is javascript not jquery

Comment: Why would you like to chain it? Just wrap the last lines in an if-statement.

Comment: @AnishGupta - correct. I tagged it tough

Comment: @JonasStensved - isn't chaining supposed to be better than doing a lot of if-elses?

Comment: chaining has nothing to do with `if-else`

Comment: @frequent If you're introducing if-else I wouldn't consider it chaining but branching. You could chunk it down a level and create a function with an conditional statement inside.

Comment: Shorthand seriously makes the code harder to interpret when it comes to maintenance.   I would urge you to stick to the traditional {} approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of plug-ins that allow you to chain `if` logic in jQuery -

http://outwestmedia.com/jquery-plugins/conditional/

```
$('div')
    .If('hasClass', 'myClass')
        .css('color', 'red')
    .Else('hasClass', 'anotherClass')
        .css('color', 'green')
    .Else()
        .css('color', 'blue');
```

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-iff-plugin/

```
function my_test( x ) {
  return x === 'bar';
};

$('div')
  .append( '1' )
  .iff( my_test, 'foo' )
    .append( '2' )
    .end()
  .append( '3' );
```

Answer (score 4):

That will do (assignment uses a single =, two is for conditions), but if the first one is true, like you posted, some will ALWAYS be true.

```
var some = true || "it's true";
```

And no, your example wouldn't be chainable, but you could replace your hasClass by `filter('.one')` which will continue the chain if there are elements containing the class one:

```
some.addClass("hello")
      .find(".other").css("width","100px").end()
      .filter('.one').css("border","1px solid red")
      .removeClass("hello")
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing. That returns `true` if `some == true`, and `"it's true"` otherwise.

Comment: that [won't even work](http://jsfiddle.net/NjcRt/) at all (double equals? seriously?)

Comment: Makes no sense; you're always assigning `some` to `true`.

Comment: I edited the post, I copy pasted the origin poster code which was wrong as it was using == instead of = to do its assignement -> http://jsfiddle.net/NjcRt/1/

Comment: @Dave I am only following the poster example... Otherwise yeah I know

Answer (score 4):

The shorthand IF/ELSE you are reffering to is called a ternary operator, and it's not chainable in the same way as a IF/ELSE statements, nor is it chainable as a jQuery method, and there are some limits to it's use, you can however place one inside the other, like so:

```
some == true ? someMore == true ? "it's true" : "it's false" : "it's false";
```

You can also do:

```
some == true ? "it's true" : null;
//or
some == true ? "it's true" : undefined;
```

This returns something, so usually it's used like so:

```
var some = someVar==true ? "it's true" : "it's false";
```

In other words you can do:

```
var some = $(some).length ? 
             $(some).is('.one') ?
               some //some exists and have the class .one
             :
               return someOtherVar or function //some does not have the class .one
           :
             undefined //some does not have a length
           ;
```

You could also do something similar to this, and there are many different ways to use a ternary:

```
$(div)[somevar==true ? fadeIn : fadeOut](300);
```

Other than that, when having a lot of stuff to perform a if/else is usually more appropriate, and if doing  a lot of if/else/elseif checking, a switch/case is probably better.

Comment: `var` statements are statements, but not expressions, so they can't be inside a ternary operator.

Comment: @DelanAzabani - Your right, a little to much copy/paste. Fixed it!